# How to insert image in room database?

Tags: android, image, android-room

I am using room persistence library for my android application, I have to insert image in my database. I have an Entity Picture and an Entity Folder .
So now, my question is how to save picture and folder into room database?.
Also i need to know how to store picture in folder !

Picture.java

```
@Entity
public class Photo implements Serializable
{
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)

private int idP;
private String titre;
private String date , heure ;

public int getIdP() {
    return idP;
}

public void setIdP(int idP) {
    this.idP = idP;
}

public String getTitre() {
    return titre;
}

public void setTitre(String titre) {
    this.titre = titre;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getHeure() {
    return heure;
}

public void setHeure(String heure) {
    this.heure = heure;
}
```

Folder.java

```
@Entity
public class Dossier implements Serializable {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int idD;

private String titre;

public Dossier(String titre) {
    this.titre = titre;
}

public int getIdD() {
    return idD;
}

public void setIdD(int idD) {
    this.idD = idD;
}

public String getTitre() {
    return titre;
}

public void setTitre(String titre) {
    this.titre = titre;
}
}
```