# How to code a function who updates a specific attribute

Tags: java, android

I need to create a function which calculate age of pregnancy. It has on entry a date then calculate the age and return an int ( number of weeks or days if it’s not a week yet).
But, this number should be incremented each week.
Could please help me to create this function !
Thank you.

Comment: _It has on entry a date ...._ What date would this be?

Comment: Date of the beginning of pregnancy

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show your code?

Comment: No I haven’t tried, I don’t have any idea how to do that that’s

Comment: _Date of the beginning of pregnancy..._ ..which is unknown usually ;)

Comment: this isn't the problem @B001ᛦ I want the function (I have the date of the beginning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to calculate the number of days/weeks between the entry date and the current date, you could use the following methods:

```
long daysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(LocalDate.of(year, month, date), LocalDate.now());

long weeksBetween = ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between(LocalDate.of(year, month, date), LocalDate.now());
```

They compare the time between the LocalDate instance created for your entry (specified by year, month, and date) and the current date now.

With regards to returning the number of days as an int if weeks < 1, I think that this could lead to some confusion as there would be an uncertainty of if the return value is in days or weeks (i.e. if the function returns 5, is that 5 days or 5 weeks?) Perhaps instead you return both of them (in some sort of struct) or settle for just weeks?

Comment: So using just the weeksBetween calculation should work. If it needs to be int, you can cast it using (int)weeksBetween.

Comment: And ho to inrement this value after each week ?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you intend to run the program continuously throughout multiple weeks?

Comment: I'm creating an android apps for pregnant women so yes the program runs continuously

Comment: It runs continuously as in they never close the app on their phone for the duration of their pregnancy? I think that instead you mean they periodically check the app and want to know the current week count, right? In that case, this calculation will automatically “increment” with each passing week as every time you run it it’ll recalculate.

Comment: But this function will be called just one time (when she press button calculate) and the result will be stored in the attribute "weeks_ofpreg" so how it’ll recalculate ?

Comment: Each week she presses "calculate" it'll recalculate the week count. If you want something automatic, consider calling the function every time they open the application or based on a timer.

Comment: Okey could you just indicate me how to do timer to increment with week ! Also I want to ask you : Date is deprecated I replaced it with Calendar but it doesn’t work for me ? What should I do ?

Comment: First off, I'm just trying to help please don't get angry... What do you mean incriment with week? Do you intend that the app will remain open and on the screen for an entire week? If not, then my other suggestion of whenever the app loads to recalculate should work. Regarding Date, yes the Date class is deprecated which is why I'm using the LocalDate class.

Comment: Sorry if It seems I'm angry thank you very much for helping .
So for the entry I have to give (int year,int month,int day)?

Comment: Yes, by defining the entry point with int year, int month, int day, that line will be able to calculate the number of weeks from the entry point to the current date.

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly can I ask u one question about spinner ?

Comment: Spinner? Perhaps you start a new question if this is a different problem and I'll take a look there.

Comment: Coud you help me on this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56690719/how-to-insert-image-in-room-data-base-and-save-it-into-folder/56690799#56690799